# c program of strcat using pointers

Tags: c

Please run it on your machine using gcc and tell if it also gives you a segmentation fault output. I don't think there is any problem with the program. I am a beginner in C.  So Help!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *scat(char *,char *);

void main()
{
    char *s="james";
    char *t="bond";

    char *w=scat(s,t);
    printf("the con: %s\n", w);
    free(w);
}

char *scat(char *s,char *t)
{ 
    char *p=malloc(strlen(s)+strlen(t)+1); 
    int temp=0 , ptr=0;

    while(s[temp]!='\0'){
        p[ptr++]=s[temp++];
    } 
    temp=0;
    while(t[temp]='\0'){
        p[ptr++]=t[temp++];
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault, so the program has a problem...

Comment: You should probably try formatting your code better.

Comment: First mistake: "I don't think there is any problem with the program"

Comment: memcpy() is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second loop has no effect:

```
while(t[temp]='\0') { // <<== Assignment!!!
    p[ptr++]=t[temp++];
}
```

This should be a `!=` not `=`, or better yet, you can drop zero altogether:

```
while(t[temp]) { // Zero-checking is implicit in C
    p[ptr++] = t[temp++];
}
```

Since you are not writing to `s` or `t`, it's probably a good idea to declare them both `const`. This would have caught the assignment in the `while` loop above.

Comment: It should probably be `!=`. Good catch!

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for catching the `==` vs. `!=` :)

Comment: And since string literals are passed in, that is probably where it crashes.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, so it's probably a good idea to declare both params `const`.

Comment: have run it on your gcc compiler and seen it?

Comment: @KundanNegi Here is the [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/4w1Zox) with your running program.

Comment: we all are fools! i just forgot to put ! in second while loop. Even then Thanks a lot for sparing your precious time for me!!!!!

Comment: @KundanNegi `-Wall` would have saved us all a lot of time :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Ya i know that its bad to reimplement the built-in codes. but it was an exercise for me. So Thanks a lot all of you !!!!!

Comment: @KundanNegi If you are no longer looking for an improved solution, you should accept one of the answers by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would indicate that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for your kind advice. I just created account in stackoverflow so didn't know that. I'll do it right know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't 0-terminate the string in `scat`. You could add:

```
p[ptr] = 0;
```

Right before returning.

Comment: please run it own your gcc compiler and tell me?

Comment: Naw man, it could wake Cthulhu because of the undefined behavior. WHOOPS!

Answer (score 0):

1. *Please run it on your machine using gcc and tell if it **also** gives you a segmentation fault output.*
2. *I don't think there is any problem with the program.*

I don't follow your reasoning. If the program segfaults on your system then it is **very** likely that the program is at fault.

[FYI this is what GCC(*) outputs.](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b7a9b84f6a0ec030d7aa9d569dde3611) It doesn't even compile.

NOTE: It's g++ actually, but it shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: was that output with `-Wall`, mr strawhat?

Comment: i copied this same program some a person. his program works and mine not. i rechecked both the programs 10 times but still the problem persist

Comment: @Mike it's compiled with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic-errors`

Comment: @KundanNegi - Google search or look at the man for gcc, there are a lot of extra flags that will give you more details and help you find errors/warnings with your code

Comment: @KundanNegi Options that make the compiler tell you where your code looks fishy.

Comment: +1 for -Wall & friends, -1 for compiling C code as C++ :) so you're even ;)

Comment: ya -Wall feature is great. Thanks a lot everyone. I solved the problem now. Stackoverflow ROCKS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to emulate the functions that exist in string.h:

```
#include <string.h>

char *scat(char *s,char *t)
{ 
    char *p;
    size_t len1, len2;
    len1 = strlen(s);
    len2 = strlen(t);

    p=malloc(len1+len2+1);
    if (!p) barf();
    memcpy(p,s, len1);
    memcpy(p+len1, t, len2+1);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: ya i know my friend but it is an exercise i want to try.

Comment: talking about functions that exist in string.h: `strcat()`

Comment: @KundanNegi reimplementing functions that are part of the C standard is generally a bad idea. Try exercising the use of said functions with a more complex example instead and you'll learn more useful aspects of the language.

Comment: Well, if you really want to avoid library functions, you could roll your own strlen(), too.